# Setting MFSideMenu after showing user content with UIPageViewController - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am using storyboard in app which first shows a First Time Usage Page with UIPageViewController.

When it is finished and user signs up, it will head to MFSideMenu.

I am holding MFSideMenu in another storyboard.

When user presses to sign up and it is successful the method below is fired.

```
-(IBAction)continueButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

AppDelegate *appDel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SideMenu" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)appDel.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftMenuViewController"];
UIViewController *rightSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightMenuViewController"];

[container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
[container setRightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuViewController];
[container setCenterViewController:navigationController];

[appDel.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

But i am taking exception as

[UINavigationController setLeftMenuViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What am i missing?

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are choosing a navigation view as your root view Please set your sidemen container view as ur initial view in your storyboard. This will work for your View.
Please refer the image: [image]